# Installing Debian without GUI for a web server

Tags: linux, debian, system-installation, webserver

I'm unfamiliar with Debian (obviously), so I downloaded the live ISO thinking it might help me. From the live GUI, I doubled click on the install icon on the desktop and proceeded - it gave me an install with GNOME and a bunch of other software that has no business being on a web server. Generally.

So the first part of my question is, can I install the base/non-GUI version from the Live disc? If so, how? If not, can someone point me to the correct download for the amd64 bit version?

I want what would be the Debian equivalent to Ubuntu Server - a simple, bare-bones, non-GUI OS. I prefer to install my HTTP server as well - I'm not sure if I'll be going with Apache or Nginx or handling HTTP requests myself in node.js...

Answer (score 24):

Download the netinstall iso, boot it and select non-graphical install. I actually made a video once for it: 
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JOGSupJury4

The difference between ubuntu and debian is the way they are doing package testing. Debian is all about stability and ubuntu is more about all the new things (less stability).

Comment: ^ *that* - There's a few other options in the debian installer I've not seen in ubuntu as well. There's no practical reason for using a GUI livecd to install a CLI install whatsoever.

Comment: You can even use the graphical install and it will not install a graphics server if you don't select a desktop environment. It just uses some basic graphics for the installer, allowing to use it a bit easier with a mouse. It even almost looks the same, but you can change the focus with the mouse and don't have to press the arrow keys often to switch to the correct entry of a list and so on. In the end it doesn't matter, but using the netinstall (or full install DVD) instead of the live image is the important part.

Answer (score 16):

You have to deselect **desktop environment** from **software selection** during the install in order to get a non-GUI Debian install.