# Debian equivalent to Ubuntu server

Tags: debian, ubuntu, debian-installer, debian-cd

I am trying to install Debian 9.5 on my company's server. Problem ! I can't install it without the GUI (I don't need it and I don't want it to be there).

I tried [all this .iso](https://cdimage.debian.org/debian-cd/current-live/amd64/iso-hybrid/) and the installation process **is not giving me the choice of programs to install** (as referred in this [similar question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/51927/installing-debian-without-gui-for-a-web-server?newreg=e9daf1aadebd48378a7bfc8dda0b8fa9) )

I found a lot of blog posts talking about installing the debian from the netinstall .iso BUT this suppose that the server is already connected to internet (**Not in my case**)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yesterday I installed Debian 9.5 without installing X (during installation) using the netinstall iso, but I'm quite sure it uses the same installer as full cds/dvds. It did the last time I tried any of those.

I think your problem might be that you're using live images. They are probably geared to install something very similar to what they present, and they all have a desktop environment in their name.

Try going to [Getting Debian](https://www.debian.org/distrib/) and follow the link to "A larger [complete installation image](https://www.debian.org/CD/)", from there you should be able to download some cd/dvd images from which you can install without an internet connection.